# Convert Mode to ViewModel

Tags: c#

I , in a special case I dont want to use automepper , this is my convertion method to Model to ViewModel :

```
public static BlogPostViewModel ConvertToBlogPostViewModel(this BlogPost blogPost)
        {
            var blogPostViewModel = new BlogPostViewModel
                {
                    Body = blogPost.Body,
                    Summary = blogPost.Summary,
                    Title = blogPost.Title
                };

            return blogPostViewModel;
        }
```

now how Can I do this for IEnumerable of the same method() !??

```
public static IEnumerable<BlogPostViewModel> ConvertToBlogPostViewModelList(this IEnumerable<BlogPost> blogPosts)
        {
            ??

        }
```

thanks !

Comment: Just call ConvertToBlogPostViewModel for each item in the loop and build a collection of converted view model objects.

Comment: Look at [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx), especially with conjunction with your current method (`ConvertToBlogPostViewModel`).

Comment: so , call ConvertToBlogPostViewModel ?? how ??

Comment: See http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/LINQ/Constructornewobjectwithselectstatement.htm, there's an example on how to use Select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the whole body of your method:

```
return blogPosts.Select(ConvertToBlogPostViewModel);
```

It's an equivalent to:

```
return blogPosts.Select(x => ConvertToBlogPostViewModel(x));
```